# Android service killed right after removing the app from "Recents"

Tags: android, service, background-process

I have a service that needs to run even if you close the app that launched it.

The behaviour I want to achieve is totally similar to the Play Music app+service: if you're listening to music, even if you close the app, even if you remove the app from the apps list (using the 3rd button in Android, "Recents") the service still plays music and shows a notification to change the song, stop the music, etc.

In my app, if the service is running and I totally close the app using the method above, I don't even get a call to onDestroy() of the service. It just get killed.

That's how I implemented the service:

1. I created my service by extending IntentService
2. In my Activity, when a button is pressed, I launch the Service this way:

---

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FixService.class);
intent.putExtra(...);
startService(intent);
```

So, what's the most correct method to achieve that behaviour? Should I extend the `Service` class or should I create an `AIDL` file? Should I declare the Service to run in a different process? And then, how to call the service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use alarm manager to reinvoke the service
http://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/